# C++ Optimize if/else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization

I wrote the following code to simulate and simplify what is happening in my application.

In this simplification, I have the **if** and **else** branch that are executing the same code, but writing in a different portion of memory. So I thought to use an array of two entries, and depending the statement condition the first or the second entry is updated.
This solution brings the expected speed up.

But when during the execution we have a **random access** for each iteration, the improvement almost disappears. To show this bizarre behavior, I have used the template to activate or deactivate the use of if-statement and random access, i.e..
**useif**: true when the if-statement is used, false when the memory access is used.
**rand_access**: true when we have a random access for each iteration, false otherwise.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#define N 1000000000
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template <bool useif, bool rand_access>
void exec(vector<int>& V, vector<bool>& B) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int sum[2], sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    sum[0] = 0; sum[1] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        const int index = (rand_access) ? V[i] : i;
        if ( useif ){
            if ( B[index] ) sum2 += V[i];
            else sum1 += V[i];
        } else
            sum[B[index]] += V[i];
    }
    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Time useif="<<useif<<", rand_access="<<rand_access<<" : " << t.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (sum1+sum2+sum[0]+sum[1]) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> V(N);
    vector<bool> B(N, false);
    iota( V.begin(), V.end(), 0 );
    random_shuffle( V.begin(), V.end() );
    fill( B.begin(), B.begin() + B.size()/2, true);
    random_shuffle( B.begin(), B.end() );
    exec<false, false>(V, B);
    exec<false, true>(V, B);
    exec<true, false>(V, B);
    exec<true, true>(V, B); 
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, compiling with g++ --std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -mtune=native, I obtain the following results:
Time useif=0, rand_access=0 : **1518** ms
Time useif=0, rand_access=1 : **10791** ms
Time useif=1, rand_access=0 : **4384** ms
Time useif=1, rand_access=1 : **12214** ms

So, there is a speed up of **2.8** substituting the if-statement with a memory access, when there is **NOT** a random access involved, otherwise the performance are really close (**1.1** speed up).

I don't understand why this is happening and how can I deal with it, i.e. how can I **optimize** the if-statement knowing that the **if** and **else** branch are executing the same code?

Comment: You complied with the optimization flags on, right?

Comment: you should get memory address of `V` and `B` and access the C-array. There's some overhead on accessing vector `[]`. And random access is less effective because of the impossibility of using memory cache prefetch.

Comment: cache misses cause delays when using random access. pipeline stalls when using "if"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your optimization of `if`/`else` with an array is the correct one. It always gives you an improvement, but the significance of the improvement depends on other factors as well.

Your experiment shows relative impacts of branch elimination and cache access optimization.

When the code accesses memory in order, it takes advantage of CPU cache optimization due to locality of reference, "paying" for only a small fraction of its memory accesses. With 64-byte cache lines, it acts like an incredible "buy one, get fifteen free" policy for 4-byte integers stored in consecutive locations. It lets your CPU keep on adding with very little wait for the data from memory.

When the code has no branching, it takes advantage of CPU instruction pipeline. Hitting an `if` with a condition that is hard to predict stalls the pipeline, so fewer instructions are "in flight" at the same time.

Going from random access with branching to sequential access with branching saves you 7.8 seconds; eliminating branching saves you an additional 2.8 seconds on top of that.

In contrast, eliminating branching without sequential access gives you only a 1.5 seconds improvement, because eliminating pipeline stalls becomes a lot less important when the CPU is waiting for memory anyway.

Comment: you have said that this optimization always gives an improvement. But I have found in my application, that this optimization goes  slower then the one with if-statement. To remove the if-statement, I use an array of two struct that holds that data that have to change and has a method "update" that change all this data. Is it correct proceed in this way in your opinion? Why do you think it is slower?

Comment: @Draxent If the `struct` is large enough, the cost of writing additional data may end up eating the savings from not stalling the pipeline. In some rare situations you may be able to skip the `else` portion of the operation in the loop, and do the computation after the loop in a single computation. In your example, this would be assigning `sum1 = n*(n+1)/2 - sum2`.